# Changes to the manifest of my azure app are not seen in the azure portal

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azureportal

I want to programatically mirror AWS IAM Roles to my SAML federation, using a lambda, with lambda [like this developer](https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/aws-saml-azuread)

I want to verify what the least privilege access the credentials for the automation software need to have in Azure, so i tried a simple python script to mimic this (see below).

I am able to update the value and retrieve the updated value, but when I go into the Azure portal and look at the manifest file, it has not changed.

Now I am wondering why this is the case: Is there caching going on in the Python CLI for Azure? Am I not catching some underlying errors in the right way?

```
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
from azure.graphrbac.models.app_role import AppRole

credentials = UserPassCredentials(
            username='my-user@company',
            password='my-ad-password',
            resource="https://graph.windows.net"
    )

tenant_id = "guid-of-my-company-tenant-from-ad-admins"
graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)
oid = "guid-of-object-id"
principal = graphrbac_client.service_principals.get(object_id=oid)
print('display_name: {}'.format(principal.display_name))
try:
    for role in principal.app_roles:
        if( role.display_name == 'AWSRoleInManifestFile'):
            print("is_enabled: ", role.is_enabled)

    # Verify update works by changing one role to isEnabled = false
    for role in principal.app_roles:
        if( role.display_name == 'AWSRoleInManifestFile'):
            role.is_enabled = False

    # Update using the api.
    retval = graphrbac_client.service_principals.update(oid, principal)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occured.", e)

# retrieve the values again to see if the change is done.
principal = graphrbac_client.service_principals.get(object_id=oid)

for role in principal.app_roles:
    if( role.display_name == 'AWSRoleInManifestFile'):
        print("role.is_enabled: ", role.is_enabled)
print("done.")
```

Using the raw parameter for the update call, I can see that it is a PATCH request that is sent, and the response is 204.

```
retval = graphrbac_client.service_principals.update(object_id=oid, parameters=principal, custom_headers=None, raw=True)
```

Comment: This is not an issue of Python, but instead something within the Azure portal. I was able to verify this occurs with the REST api provider by the https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/ using GET and PATCH respectively on https://graph.windows.net/MY_TENTANT_ID/servicePrincipals/MY_APP_ID